# How to make Perfmon automatically track same process for IIS with multiple sites?

Tags: iis-6, perfmon, performance-counters

I'm doing performance/load testing of my IIS6/Win2K3 server.  I setup perfom by adding performance counters for the specific site I'm interested in (ie. w3wp#7).

The problem is -- I have to manually complete these steps for each test run assuming my load test causes an automatic recycle of the application pool (OR if the test server is restarted or an iisreset happens).

Is there an easier way to setup a Counter Log with the specific counters I want that will automatically monitor the process I'm interested in.  Obviously the site stays the same, its just the process that sometimes changes.

Any help would be great for productivity.

Thanks!

jg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's what I did.  I made the registry tweak that displayed the PIDS in the Perfmon counter "instance" list.  From here, I wrote a batch script that sent a request via TinyGet to the webserver in question (to make sure the IIS worker process was started) THEN ran the IISAPP command and simply searched for the PID of the application pool I was interested in.  From there, I could use the PID in the Perfmon counters by name.  Took a while, but worth it!